# Android Recycler view OnItemTouch work only click on text view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` where I have added addOnItemTouchListener to process touch event.

The code is following  and it is working any where where I click on card view which is used to create `RecyclerView`.

```
      mRecyclerDrawer.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mRecyclerDrawer, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                ((ActivityMain) getActivity()).onDrawerItemClicked(position - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));



 static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }
    }
```

But the problem is in my use case that I have a card view which have some text in one `TextView` and a second `TextView` named read more so I want onClick event only to be called when I click on "Read more" `TextView`, not any where on the CardView.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your approach is the best. If you read carefully the documentation, it states:

> public void addOnItemTouchListener (RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener
>   listener)
>
> Add an RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener to intercept touch events
>   before they are dispatched to child views or this view's standard
>   scrolling behavior.
>
> Client code may use listeners to implement item manipulation behavior.
>   Once a listener returns true from onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView,
>   MotionEvent) its onTouchEvent(RecyclerView, MotionEvent) method will
>   be called for each incoming MotionEvent until the end of the gesture.

I think you should simply call `View.setOnClickListener` from within the adapter, for each item view.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(YourOnClickListenerGoesHere);
    holder.mTextView.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@mdelolmo's answer is a better approach but instead use `onCreateViewHolder` to add the listener instead of `onBind`. Also, if you really want to use your approach, you should be returning true from the `onInterceptTouch` method when you don't want children to handle it.